# facebook login application for phonegap in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am new to Facebook applications.

1) what is the procedure for implementing Facebook application.

2) I want a sample login application in java script which uses phonegap.

Could you please send the reply.

Thanks in advance.
swathi

Comment: The procedure is to go to Facebook's developers site and look at their documentation on how to implement it.  Google will probably help you find examples.  The point of this site is not to tell HOW to do it, but rather assist you when you're stuck ACTUALLY doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to what you ask using [this connector](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect) and following base phonegap tutorials, you shouldn't have problems in doing that.
If you want the code done for you, you are in the wrong place, pleas show some effort before asking and the community will help you.